# R not generated, XML file contains error but which XML file?

Tags: android, xml, debugging

My R file is not generated after I clean my project. And according to my research on stack overflow, I think I have an error in my xml file but I dont know which xml contains the bug. I went through all of them including the AndroidManifest file.

Is there any way or tool to help me find out which xml contains the error? I have been stuck with this problem for like 10 hours. Please Help!

p.s
I have 2 different custom view where both have the same namespace (but uses in separate xml file), is that a problem?

**AndroidManifest file**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.packagename.appname"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="15"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.Fullscreen" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.packagename.appname.activity.SplashScreenActivity"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_app"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:noHistory="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.glass.action.VOICE_TRIGGER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.glass.VoiceTrigger"
                android:resource="@xml/voice_trigger" />
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.packagename.appname.activity.MainActivity"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.packagename.appname.activity.SelectActionActivity"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Problems View**

[image: This is how my problem view looks like. I dont see anything useful here.]

Comment: Post your manifest file.

Comment: look into problems view on eclipse and filter the errors or find the error in xml files

Comment: Thanks for the quick help. Heres my manifest file. Do I seriously have to post my xml file, theres like 13 of them ...

Comment: Have a look at the Console tab to see possible error output from aapt.

Comment: How can you be sure that there is an error in one of the xml files as the red mark is not showing! in my case after cleaning the project R.java is not regenerated ! For that i simply **restart** the Eclipse & R.java was regenerated after the workspace was completely build.
Have you tried Restarting the eclipse ????

Comment: @VivekWarde I tried restarting eclipse but that didnt change anything.

Comment: @laalto How exactly can I produce those error? I think I was able to get some error message by going into individual xml and hit save before. But I dont seem to be able to do that now for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the bug... I declared the same id twice in the ids.xml. I would like to share how I found which xml contains the error. So I copied out individual xml content and deleting them from the project to see if the R file would generated. For all the non-xml, I set them to not including into build path for the time being. Its not the best way to find a error but it is a way. Thanks for everyone who reply to question. Happy coding.